# Primefaces - Intercept error message, and show my own

Tags: jsf, primefaces, converters, message

I have an input field, `<p:inputText>`. Im setting the data to a `long attribute`.
If I write a something else than a letter, then im getting an error message on my `<p:messages>`.

This is behavior that I want.

But is it possible to intercept the message, and print my own insted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<p:inputText>` has attribute for it `validatorMessage=""` or `requiredMessage=""`(required message is displayed if field is required but not filled) if your error appear in converter you can also use `converterMessage=""`

ps. Feel free to use localized strings in it.